# Is it possible to share data between MATLAB objects, for example a look-up table?

Tags: matlab, oop

I have written a handle class in MATLAB in which I overload the "*" operator via `function obj = mtimes(a,b)`, where `a` and `b` are supposed to be objects from that class. My problem is the following. Within the function `mtimes`, I need to have access to some "external" data, in particular a look up table (LUT) which I calculate in the very beginning of my code, so this LUT should somehow be available to all objects from that class. I could of course create a property in the class definition and initialize each object with that LUT, but this would be impractical since the table is quite large and would be copied to each object? I am not very familiar with OOP in general, so any suggestions on how to solve this problem are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I assume you mean the "*" operator, not the "+" operator.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Should be "*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're saying there is one universal, unchanging LUT that all objects use, you could make it a Constant property. That way it will be computed only the first time the class is referenced.

Comment: I think the OP may be using "copy" to refer to each instance object of a class. Are you saying that if one creates several instances of a class that each have a constant property, only one version of that data will reside some place in memory?

Comment: @horchler Yes. Constant properties are "constant" in the fullest sense of the word. You don't even need an instance of the class to access them, only the class name, `ClassName.PropertyName`

Comment: Thanks. Some details on [properties with constant values](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/properties-with-constant-values.html) can be found here.

Comment: @Matt: Little follow up question. In the `properties (constant)` block, how can I call a method that belongs to the class? I was able to refer to other constant via `classname.variablename` but `classname.functionname()` did not work.

Comment: You can't call a class method, but there's no reason the method you're calling should need to be a class method. Just make it a subfunction. Classdef files can contain subfunctions.

Comment: You can call a class method to instantiate a Constant property if the method is Static.

Answer (score 2):

You could also make LUT a persistent variable in the constructor, like below. This would afford you the flexibility of changing the table on object construction. You should be careful to issue `clear classes` before altering the table, however.

```
classdef myclass < handle

  properties

   LUT

  end  


  methods

   function obj=myclass(newtable)

     persistent LUT

     if isempty(LUT) && nargin

      LUT=newtable;

     elseif nargin

      warning 'Clear all previous objects'

      LUT=newtable;

     end


    obj.LUT=LUT;

   end

 end

end
```